Basic case of the vanishing of the Tate-Shafarevich Group
Following is Theorem (9.1.9)(i) from Cohomology of Number Fields by Neukirch, Schmidt and Wingberg
Let $k$ be a global ﬁeld and let $S$ be a set of primes of $k$.
$(i)$ For a finite and trivial $G_{S}(k)$-module $A$ and the sets of primes $T \subseteq S$ of $k$, if $\delta(T) > \frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of #$A$, then the map
$$\text{res}^{1} : H^{1}(k_{S}|k, \mathbb{Z}/p^{r}\mathbb{Z}) \longrightarrow \prod_{p \in T} H^{1}(k_{p}, \mathbb{Z}/p^{r}\mathbb{Z})$$ has trivial kernel.
Here, $k_{S}$ is used for the maximal extension of $k$ in its algebraic-closure that is unramified outside $S$, $G_{S}(k)$ is the notation for the Galois group Gal$(k_{S}/k)$ and $\delta$ is the Dirichlet density in $K$.
The proof in the book used Chebotarev's density theorem (CDT) after reducing to the case of $A = \mathbb{Z}/p^{r}\mathbb{Z}$ for some $p$, without loss of generality. If a non-zero map $\varphi : G_{k_{S}|k} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{r}\mathbb{Z} $ exists in the kernel of res$^{1}$ then ker$(\varphi) \leq G_{S}(k)$ corresponds to a cyclic extension $L/k$ of degree $p^{s}$ with $0 \leq s \leq r$, where $L = k_{S}^{ker(\varphi)}$. And this extension $L$ is unramified outside $S$ and completely split at $T$. Since CDT implies that the density of completely split primes in this extension is supposed to be $\frac{1}{p^{s}}$, only way $\delta(T) > \frac{1}{p}$ can work is when $s = 0$, meaning $L = k$. So, ker$(\varphi) = G_{k_{S}|k}$, i.e., $\varphi = 0$ identically.
My question is when $k$ does not contain $p^{th}$ roots of unity, would the same conclusion hold if $\delta(T) = \frac{1}{p}$? It would from CDT if the Galois extension $L := k_{S}^{\text{ker}(\varphi)}$ was of degree $p^{2}$ and above.
However, if $L$ above was an extension of degree $p$, then the quotient $G_{k_{S}|k}/\text{ker}(\varphi) \cong \text{Gal}(k(\zeta_{p})|k)$ will be of order $p$; more specifically, cyclic of order $p$. Then, each element would be its own conjugacy class and set of primes whose Artin symbol would be a conjugacy class would have density $\frac{1}{p}$ exactly, using Chebotarev density theorem. Note that the extension $L$ splits at $T$, and $\delta(T)$ is exactly $\frac{1}{p}$ - I feel that this should work out. However, I cannot seem to get through this. Any help/comments/admonishing would be appreciated.

Well, that is fixed now.. Thanks.. Any thoughts on the actual question though?

I'm not sure I understand your question, because I do not get why whether $k$ contains $p$th roots of unity is relevant, but I believe the answer should be no. The bound $\delta(T)>\frac1p$ is optimal in the sense that for any number field $K$ and abelian group $A$ with trivial Galois action, there is some set $T$ with $\delta(T)=1/p$ and $\text{Sha}^1(\bar{K}/K,T,A)\neq 0$.
I will show this for $A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but the proof for general $A$ is similar. Let $K$ be a number field, $S$ the set of all places of $K$, and $A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Given $\varphi\in H^1(K,A)$, we will construct a set of primes $T$ with $\delta(T)=1/p$ and $\text{Sha}^1(K_S/K,T,A)\neq 0$. As you did, let $L=\bar{K}^{\ker(\varphi)}$, which is a $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-extension of $K$. Let $T=cs(L/K)$ be the set of primes of $K$ completely split in $L$. By Chebotarev density, we have $\delta(T)=\frac1p$. We claim $\varphi$ is locally trivial at all places $\mathfrak{p}\in T$. By definition of $T$, we have that $L_\mathfrak{p}/K_\mathfrak{p}$ is the trivial extension, but this is exactly equivalent to $\text{res}_\mathfrak{p} \varphi=0$ (this equivalence is the main idea of the proof of 9.1.9(i).) Since $\text{res}_{\mathfrak{p}}\varphi=0$ for all $\mathfrak{p}\in T$, we obtain $\varphi\in \text{Sha}^1(\bar{K}/K,T,A)\neq 0$.
Beyond just this, there is something confusing me about your last paragraph. You mention that $G_{k_S|k}/\ker(\varphi)\cong \text{Gal}(k(\zeta_p)/k)$ will be order $p$. It is true that $G_{k_S/k}/\ker(\varphi)$ should be order $p$, but it should not be isomorphic to $\text{Gal}(k(\zeta_p)/k)$. In general, $k(\zeta_p/k)$ should be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$, which is a group of order $p-1$, so it should never be order $p$.
